# How to get latitude and longitude details by passing address

Tags: sql, db2, talend

I have address `field_1`, `Feils_2` and `city_name`, `Country_name`, `Zip_code` in a `Customer` table (DB2 database) and I need to populate `Latitude` and `Longitude` based on the address.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You'll need a bit more than those tools to find a geolocation, unless you happen to be holding some map data as well...  Do you have access to external (web) services?

Answer (score 1):

Use googlemaps webservice, but there is a limit to how many you can look up daily without paying for an account.

Answer (score 0):

This georeferencial information is not available in DB2 (Retrieve a pair of coordinates from an address). You can create functions in DB2 implemented in Java or C, and with these functions query an external system that has this information. Once the functions got the coordinates, it can be passed by to DB2.

With the previous answer, it recommended to use GoogleMaps, but it did not explain how to use from DB2. With my solution, you can create a Java function in DB2 that will query the GoogleMaps API to retrieve the coordinates. However, not all countries/places are in the GoogleMaps Database, and you could need to use another georeferential system.